# Single shared codebase shared among different .net versions

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-2.0, versioning

I looked around to see if there's an example of the question I'm about to ask before I dive into it. But let's say I have a codebase that is pointing to .NET 2.0 framework, I need to still keep it as such, but I also want to create a new version of the project pointing to the 4.0 framework.

Is it possible to create a solution, have two projects, one for .NET 2.0 and another for .NET 4.0. Have a "shared" codebase between the two, knowing they will be the same for those two projects?

Like there's a few cs, aspx, and ascx files that I know will be the same no matter what version I use.. can I have it shared and have the project use those shared files and compile a dll into the versioning that I need?

This is so I don't have to keep on updating files for two versions of the product; or remember that I'd have to if it ever comes to that point in the future.

**Editting with new solution**

I decided to make the solution with 3 projects.
Project-NET.2.0
Project-NET.4.0
Project-Shared

The shared project will have library classes that has the method signature and implementation. The other two projects will take that dll reference, and then I'll create a new class that uses that shared library and make the corresponding calls to it.

So shared has a class:

```
class A {
    public int _getInt(){
        return 12345;
    }
}
```

The Project-NET.4.0

```
Using Project-Shared;

public class NewClassA : WebService {
    ClassA a = new ClassA();    

    [WebMethod]
    public int getInt(){
        return a._getInt();
    }
}
```

Thank you Reed Copsey and Jon Skeet for the help. Let me also know if you see any issues with this solution too. I think this gets me exactly what I needed and all I'd have to do is update the method implentation of _getInt in classA of the "shared" project and compile that.

Comment: Do you definitely need it to be two separate projects? Before now I've used one project with different configurations instead - works very well.

Comment: I think it's safer to be separate projects. My 4.0 application uses extra libraries not found in 2.0.

Comment: I don't see why that's relevant. Presumably the *existing codebase* doesn't use those libraries, so you only need that one project to have versions for 4.0 and 2.0. This feels safer than trying to keep two project files in lockstep.

Comment: Well, actually that's the problem. My current project actually uses 4.0, but I'm creating a new solution to make it backward compatible with 2.0 because we are using an outdated technology that only uses 2.0; and that doesn't support some of the current libraries.

Comment: Well that sounds like a completely different issue. But even if you need different references in one version than in a different version, that can *still* be managed with a single project and different configurations. We do something very much like this for Noda Time, where the PCL version is a different configuration to the "standard" version.

Comment: Ah yeh, that's right, in web config you can remove and add specific assemblies and point a project to a 2.0 environment. Personally, I'd rather avoid this kind of work. Yesterday, I spent 2 hours because of a JSScript: Object not found, when I found out that the web config was coded wrong. The error never gave clues, it just pointed to the entire javascript file and said its wrong.

Comment: I wasn't talking about web.config. I was talking about the project file itself - which is more appropriate if you're talking about a class library, mind you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have two projects, each of which include the same files.  When you add a file to a project, in Visual Studio, there's an option to [add the item as a link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which causes the two projects to share the same source.

This can be advantageous in that you can have framework specific code (by not including all files in both projects), but share the code as needed.

Comment: It does mean you need to remember to add the file to both projects each time though - and I suspect renaming files etc could be painful.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it's not without disadvantages, for sure ;)

Comment: Well I did find out that trying to add files where some classes uses relevant path, that the files aren't there. So some copies you'd need to have copies of the same file in both projects :-/ Like aspx pages referring to scripts containing js files. I'm also opted to taking the Library class way. I'll update the question with that instead.